# imshow command does not show the same binary image with original

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I read the image with:

```
 W=double(imread('rose32.bmp'));
```

Then:

```
 imshow(W,[]);
```

or

```
 imshow(W);
```

[image: result]

But the shown image seems to be inverted with respect to the original image. How can I solve this problem ? Is it a MATLAB problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably caused by the formatting the the imagefile!
When you use `imread` what it returns depends of the formatting of the image in the image file. `imread` returns tree values `[A,map,transparency] = imread(___)`, where `A` might be `h`x`w`-matrix or a `h`x`w`x`3`-matrix (`h` and `w` are short for height and width) of several different possible classes (eg. `double` or `uint8`).

In the case of the `h`x`w`x`3`-matrix the output-variable `map` will be empty, and you can show the image directly using `imshow(A)`. This is called an RGB-image.

The other possibility (called an indexed image) is the `h`x`w`-matrix. In this case `map` is a colormap, and you can show the image by `imshow(A,map)`.

You can easily convert between these two types of images by `ind2rgb(A,map)` and `rgb2ind(A)`.

The other thing you need to be careful with is the class of the image.

If you have an rgb-image of class `uint8`, then the values of image will be integers between 0 and 255, whereas rgb-images of type `double` have values between 0 and 1. You should never convert an image to `double`-class by the `double`-function like you do; in stead use `im2double`.

So to solve your problem try the following code:

```
[img,map] = imread('rose32.bmp');
if ~isempty(map)
  img = ind2rgb(img,map);
end
img = im2double(img);
```

Now `imshow(img)` should show the image correctly. Or you can simply use the following code:

```
[W,map] = imread('rose32.bmp');
imshow(W,map);
```

Comment: Can I ask a quastion with similar problem ?

Question topic: Correlation value is very good but imshow command shows corrupted image

Comment: If an answer solves your problem, you might want to consider accepting it as the correct answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers